# plotting lwr and upr prediction interval on to data in R studio

Tags: r, linear-regression

my data has 200 variables, I ran the prediction interval and now im trying to plot it with my data. my current problem is that Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ. ive looked at many solutions on here and none solved my problem.

```
attach(data)

fitreg<-lm(Temp~Humidity,data=data)
xstar<-seq(min(data$Humidity),max(data$Humidity),length.out = 100)
new= data.frame(Humidity=xstar)
pi<-predict(fitreg,newdata = new, interval="predict", level = 0.95)

plot(Temp~Humidity, xlab="Humidity", ylab="Temperature", main="Regression")
abline(fitreg, col="lightblue")



lines(new, pi[,2], col="orange", lty=2)
lines(new, pi[,3], col="orange", lty=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

even though I tried this i got it to work so heres the answer for anyone who might be struggling too.

```
attach(data)

fitreg<-lm(Temp~Humidity,data=data)
xstar<-seq(min(data$Humidity),max(data$Humidity),length.out = 200)
#length change to match number of variables 
new= data.frame(Humidity=xstar)
pi<-predict(fitreg,newdata = new, interval="predict", level = 0.95)

lower<-pi[,2]
upper<-pi[,3]

plot(Temp~Humidity, xlab="Humidity", ylab="Temperature", main="Regression")
abline(fitreg, col="lightblue")



lines(xstar, lower, col="orange", lty=2)
lines(xstar, upper, col="orange", lty=2)
```